# Why i get error in dtexec command in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I'm new in `asp.net`,and want to write code to run `sql server` `dtexec`  for that purpose write this code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process si = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                si.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\";
                si.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                si.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                si.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C dtexec / f E:/Package.dtsx / set /package.variables[FilePath].Value; e:\testFile.txt";

                si.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                si.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                si.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                si.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                si.Start();
                string output = si.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                si.Close();
```

but when i run that code,get this error:

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 12.0.2000.8 for 64-bit Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Option "/" is not valid.
```

How can i solve that problem?thanks all.

Comment: You have a space after your 2nd and 3rd `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove whitespaces from this line,  like that:

```
si.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C dtexec /f E:\\Package.dtsx /set \\package.variables[FilePath].Value;e:\\testFile.txt"
```

You should also be able to run your command in cmd.exe:

```
dtexec /f e:\package.dtsx /set \package.variables[FilePath].Value;e:\testFile.txt
```

Unless it will work in cmd, it won't work also from your code.

Comment: Now get this error:Argument "" for option "set" is not valid.

Comment: thanks but i get this error: Argument ""\package.variables[FilePath].Value;"" for option "set" is not valid.

Comment: I edited my answer once again, had still one space too much. I suggest verifying your command in cmd first, as I mentioned in the answer